# Are humans social beings?

Tags: reference-request, happiness

What has been said in literature about the following question?

> Can someone, alone on a desert island for instance, have a fulfilled life without interactions with other people? Do we need other people to be happy?

I am interested in a broad overview of the debate.

Comment: I don't know what philosophers have said about this, but I don't think this is a question for philosophy, this is a question for science. I'd argue that scientifically humans are a social species, and social interaction is an intrinsic part of our lives.

Comment: @CanadianCoder I totally agree for the main question. Perhaps "Do we need other people to be happy?" is more a philosophy question.

Comment: @Keelan What do you think ? Do we have to split the question ?

Comment: @CanadianCoder there are definitely things that can be said philosophically. To mind comes e.g. Charles Taylor who makes the claim that people only form an identity in interaction with others. Yes, probably there are psychological studies into this as well. The question is what perspective the OP wants to take.

Comment: Deleuze has an essay "Desert Islands" that might be worth investigating

Comment: @CanadianCoder Saying that it is up to science to decide about that is a philosophical stance. This question is explicitly a philosophical problem at the very least since Aristotle's [πολιτικὸν ζῷον](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0058%3Abook%3D1%3Asection%3D1253a) ("man is by nature a political animal").

Comment: It is a question for science because neuro-physiological and psychological study can prove that people will be negatively impacted by lack of positive interaction, or neglect. Even from my vague understanding of human interaction, I know people are impelled to seek out positive social interactions because it increases stimulation of the sympathetic nervous system. In other words, any musings on the topic are moot because the question has an objective answer.

Comment: @CanadianCoder "Social interaction has positive biological effects" does not answer, on it own, the question "Are humans social beings?" -- that is, are social bonds part of what makes us human? Additionally, assuming the question is purely biological puts the statements "humans social beings" and "ants are social beings" on the same level. When arguing for or against that stance, one can't help but consider the matter of freedom and determinism -- and then we are back to philosophy.

Comment: Yes it does answer whether or not humans are social beings. We are biologically oriented to thrive in rich, positive, communities of other people.  I don't know how else to say it.

Comment: @CanadianCoder Let's throw a counterfactual into the mix then. Suppose that there was an elaborate virtual reality system which was able to fully supply the biological needs you mention. Would that count as "social interaction"? How would such a device affect our conception of "human"? These are not biological questions. (Obviously, my counterfactual is entirely irrelevant from a biological perspective. My point is that biology and philosophy do not compete -- they work in different planes. You don't have to choose just one of them to assign the OP's question to.)

Comment: An immense amount has been said on this question. The oldest reference that first comes to mind is Aristotle's claim that man is a social animal (mentioned above in a comment as well) -- to which he adds in *Nicomachean Ethics* that the lack of a need for society for flourishing makes one either a god or a beast.

Comment: oh wow, that's donne, was gonna say something wet about late american romantics hah https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Man_Is_an_Island

Comment: Basically if you wouldn't use Aristotle as an authority on evolution, why would you use pre-scientific philosophers as an authority on psychology and neuro-science? I'm sure much as been said, but without verifiable data backing what's been said up, literature won't hold much sway in this realm, at least to the degree that we understand the problem with science.

Comment: A lot of humans are antisocial beings.

Answer (score 1):

Some searching for studies on Google Scholar will turn up any number of articles which suggest humans have evolved as a social species with cognitive faculties which make them better adapted to interact with other humans, and thrive in environments with positive social interaction.

For instance, Herrmann, 2007

> we found that the children and chimpanzees had very similar cognitive skills for dealing with the physical world but that the children had more sophisticated cognitive skills than either of the ape species for dealing with the social world.

This suggests that our mental abilities imply that we live in complex social communities, and are oriented to survive in those communities.

Spertus, 2003

> A history of emotional abuse and neglect was associated with increased anxiety, depression, posttraumatic stress and physical symptoms, as well as lifetime trauma exposure. Physical and sexual abuse and lifetime trauma were also significant predictors of physical and psychological symptoms. Hierarchical multiple regressions demonstrated that emotional abuse and neglect predicted symptomatology in these women even when controlling for other types of abuse and lifetime trauma exposure.

This is a bit more of a stretch scientifically because it's not isolated to neglect, but neglect is the key word here. Children who are socially neglected experience, on average, more mental disorders over the course of their lifetime.

It also suggests that negative social interaction is associated with psychiatric problems.

Pedell, 2010

> This paper explores the role of domestic technologies for addressing social isolation of older people. Despite the increasing use of information and communication technologies, social isolation remains an issue amongst older people. Assistive technologies address important health needs, but there is a lack of social technologies that adequately deal with social isolation. This paper contributes to knowledge about the everyday life of older people for the purpose of designing appropriate social technology.

This paper implies that social isolation is a problem with senior citizens, and investigates ways to deal with that issue. You could go further and assume from this that, neurologically, isolation is a problem.

These are just a few examples, but I'm sure I could go on. Maybe there is something else that can be said about this, but science *does* say that if you're socially isolated you're going to run into problems.

So to directly answer the question 'can people live happily alone on a deserted island', I'd suggest that the answer is no, they can't. This line of thinking over-estimates our ability to and runs right in line with our cultural belief that people can **think** their way out of their problems.

Maybe people can think their way to happiness to a certain extent, but generally the most effective way to resolve problems is to actually get rid of the problem itself. And the studies above definitely suggest that social isolation and abuse are serious problems.

Answer (score -1):

The answer depends on the "initial conditions."
If we start with a baby, and somehow we provide sustenance so that it does not die, it will not learn/know anything about other people.  Will not even know what "fulfilled life" means.
If we start with a **very social** person over 20 years old, the most probable answer is no.  He/she will **not have** a fulfilled life.
If we start with an **antisocial hermit**, it is very likely that he/she **will have** a fulfilled life.

Comment: But the antisocial hermit will have been raised by a society. Else he won't be an antisocial hermit, he will be a feral child.